# How to install jQuery on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

How to install jQuery on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You need to add LOTS more. The version of Ubuntu. The commands you used to install or tried to install it with. Any errors or messages you got. Where are you getting this software from?

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you want it as system related files or project if it is a code.
As system:

```
sudo apt install libjs-jquery
```

As code for projects

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
sudo npm install jquery
```

Comment: Instead of installing nodejs directly, you should install `nvm` instead: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.